# how to add button for every plot in Shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to the Shiny package with R. I want to plot a dynamic number of plots and be able to control each one of them individually based on the user input for each plot. This means that it will have a set of input that will dynamically pop up for each plot.

I know from this code [here](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/) that one can dynamically add plots. From the code mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/xW8f5g5gm4s), I was able to dynamically generate the inputs too. However, I cannot place them side by side.

Giving the following output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPiqq.png)

When I try to do for two plots, I get the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK81Y.png)

What I want  is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04FgQ.png)

Could you help me with this?

The code is as follows:

```
ui.R

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots"),
    uiOutput("Dynamic")
  )
))

server.R

max_plots <- 50

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    # radioButtons(inputId = paste0("mVariable",i), label = paste0("mVariable",i), choices = c("A","B","C"))
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
    plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
    plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)

    })

    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

output$Dynamic <- renderUI({
  dynamic_selection_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
    radioButtons(inputId = paste0("mVariable",i), label = paste0("mVariable",i), choices = c("A","B","C"))
  })
  do.call(tagList, dynamic_selection_list)
})

  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  for (i in 1:max_plots) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
             xlim = c(1, max_plots),
             ylim = c(1, max_plots),
             main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n is ", input$n, sep = "")

        )
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: If you can provide the code you used to put it together, it will be easier to help you. Offhand, I'd say you need to move the UI objects in the order you want them to appear.

Comment: Take a look at Shiny modules: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html.

Comment: Hi Phil, I added the code to my original description. Please let me know if there are any more questions. bob.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using `splitLayout` along with some css script. The `splitLayout` will help you put the plot and radio button side by side. The css script is needed so that the height of radio button container is same as that of the plot. Here is the modified `ui` with which you get the desired output.

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(

    tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline)
                         {height: 280px;}")),
    splitLayout(uiOutput("plots"),
    uiOutput("Dynamic"))
  )
))
```

The output looks something like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!